# How can i plot the longitudes and latitudes sent from my android app to tomcat server and plot on the google maps there?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, tomcat

I have sent the `lat/lngs` obtained from my android to an apache tomcat server,running java for web using servlets and jsps.
I want to plot those obtained lat/lngs on the Google maps.
can any body please tell me how should and can I do that? (Using servlets and jsps)
Thanks tons in advance.

Comment: **How to add a marker in google map using javascript?** search this in google. :)

Answer (score 0):

open link in google map by using anchor tag like,

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=${latitude},${longitude}" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Sorry couldn't get ya can you please elaborate bro..in baby steps may be please

Comment: http://maps.google.com/?q=${latitude},${longitude}    is a link which will open in google map.u just have to open this link by passing longitude latitude.

Comment: can u provide a running example sample code please?